# engine light is blinking now

Tags: engine, hyundai, lights, accent

My car had no oil in it. I went and got the oil changed, and it was running better .I filled the gas tank up and then all of a sudden the engine light started blinking and it did not have power ,like to accelerate and acts rumbly or shaky.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If the engine had no oil in it, how long was it running like that for? Did it lose oil all of a sudden, or do you think the engine was running without oil for a while?

Comment: I think maybe a couple days max

Comment: How is the oil level now? Can you confirm if it is still normal by checking the dipstick?

Comment: I just had it changed yesterday so it is good and it was running better until i filled it up with gas this morning

Comment: Did the engine really have no oil in it, or was it just low?  How did you determine it had no oil in it?

Comment: They told me at valvoline that it had no oil

Comment: he also recommended to get an engine flush but i couldnt afford it for 2 weeks

Comment: Make, model and year of the car? Have you had the codes read?

Comment: 2009 hyundai accent and no I haven't

Comment: oil is above line on dipstick like one inch

Comment: Too much oil is almost as bad as not enough. And as far as Valvoline or any other *quicky* place you get your oil changed at ... the will *always* tell you of needed services. Don't pay any attention to them on this case. Pay attention to your mileage. Also, if you aren't over 100k miles, you should still have warranty on your Accent. If you actually had *no oil* in it, it would either be leaking or burning. Take it to Hyundai and have them fix it under warranty (if above applies).

Answer (score 3):

**Don't drive it like that! Flashing CEL is a "misfire", and can cause damage.**

Regardless of what happened with the oil, a flashing check engine light (CEL) almost always means there is a problem with a cylinder firing (spark is not igniting the fuel).  This also explains the hesitation, and lack of power.  This is bad because the unburned fuel can travel through the exhaust and burn inside the catalytic converter, which is then expensive to replace.

In a typical 4 cylinder engine, the car can idle, and even produce some power if 1 or 2 of the cylinders are not firing.  At idle, it might even sound normal.

I doubt this is caused by the oil level in your car, but I guess it's possible.  Last time this happened to me one of the "coils" was out, so two cylinders were not firing.  Note that it could also be something as simple as a spark plug wire that was knocked loose.

**Checking the oil level**

Just to make sure you're doing it correctly, turn the car off, parked on a level surface and let it sit for 5-10 minutes.  Pull out the dip-stick, wipe it off, and put it completely back in (don't even look at it, the reading will be wrong).  Pull it back out and carefully check the level.

Also, if there is no oil on the dipsitck, it means the car is probably 2 or more quarts low, but it doesn't mean that there is absolutely no oil in the car.  It's not good, but it doesn't mean there was damage because the car was "out of oil".  If the oil light never started to flash, you're probably fine as far as engine lubrication goes.

Comment: Ok so update , I have replaced spark plugs , ignition coils and gas cap. Now I am getting codes po420catalystsystem efficiency below thresholdBank1, po172, Bank 1 system too rich, po300, random multiple misfire cylinder misfire p303 and 304

Comment: Go ahead and post a new question or search for those codes first.  That's more than can be answered in comments.

Answer (score -1):

1 bad gas Quality , 2 bad oxygen sensor and 3 somewhere is a hole on the exhaust or exhaust manifold gasket is bad

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question...